# Configuring Angular service provider in Jasmine test

Tags: unit-testing, testing, angularjs, jasmine

I have a service on my `someModule` module:

```
someModule.provider('someService', function() {
    this.options = {};
    this.$get = function () {
        return options;
    };
});
```

I am writing a spec, and so far I have the following:

```
beforeEach(mocks.module('directives', ['someModule']));

beforeEach(function () {
    directives.config(function (someServiceProvider) {
        someServiceProvider.options({ foo: 'bar' });
    });
});
```

I need to configure my `someService` service before each test in my spec. However, the following code produces an error: `Error: Unknown provider: someServiceProvider`

What am I doing incorrectly? I thought that if I required a module, then any providers available on that module would be 'inherited'? How can I configure the `options` in my `someService` service in this test?

Answer (score 18):

By the time you call the config function your module is in the run phase. At that point you can no longer inject a provider. Try moving the function that has someServiceProvider injected into it.

```
beforeEach(module('myModule', function(someProvider) {
    someProvider.configure(1);
}));

it('should work now', inject(function(some) {
    expect(some.func()).toBeAvailable();
}));
```