# angularJS: unit tests gives: Unknown provider: $httpProviderProvider <- $httpProvider

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs

In one of my unit tests I'm trying to do

```
beforeEach(function () {
    angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
        mockUserResource = $injector.get('User');
        $httpProvider = $injector.get('$httpProvider');  // <-- problem
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
    });
});
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8FRBS/2/))

Why is it not possible to inject $httpProvider ?

The reason I'm doing this is because I don't load the file which adds all my interceptors, because I want to test them one by one!

Comment: Top notch question, so concise and easy to search for! I was having this exact problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Providers are only injectable in the config phase, `angular.config`.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323456/configuring-angular-service-provider-in-jasmine-test), you could try something like:

```
beforeEach(module('yourModule', function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
}));

beforeEach(function() {
  angular.mock.inject(function($injector) {
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    mockUserResource = $injector.get('User');
  });
});
```

For more information on how dependency injection works, [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Dependency-Injection) is a great article (not written by the AngularJS team)

Answer (score 1):

The name `Provider` is automatically added by angular.  So, you should just inject `$http`.

```
$httpProvider = $injector.get('$http');
```

here is a [working fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C9EgM/).

Comment: This is correct, just wanted to add you might want to avoid actual HTTP requests in unit tests.

Comment: I think you're forgetting that he wants to configure the `$httpProvider` using interceptors. He's not looking to inject the `$http` service.